# No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute error with websocket and stomp in springboot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

This question comes from
[relevant details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22131). When using websocket and stomp in springboot project, `No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute` error appears.

```
    // org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java
    protected ServerContainer getContainer(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
        String attrName = "javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer";
        ServerContainer container = (ServerContainer) servletContext.getAttribute(attrName);

        // container is null
        Assert.notNull(container, "No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' ServletContext attribute. " +
                "Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?");
        return container;
    }
```

I tried the following solution, but it doesn't help.

```
// layout of project
projectname
       --src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml // created manually
       --module1/src/main/java/Application.java // Class with annotiation @SpringBootApplication
       --module2/src/main/java/...
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>spring_web</name>
    </absolute-ordering>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from [this discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22131#issuecomment-575794713) that a [fix](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64021) for this issue was included in Tomcat 9.0.31, 8.5.51, and 7.0.100 releases.